# Position of always/continuously in these sentences

Tags: word-choice, word-order

I have two sentences:

**1.- On and beneath the earth's surface, new rock is made and old rock is destroyed ______________.**

**2.- The rock cycle occurs ______________________, over millions of years.**

They need to be completed with **always / continuously.**

But both of them seem really odd to me with any of the options.

Are they correctly formed? or should the adverb come before the verb?

Comment: _Continuously_ is OK but _always_ can't go at the end of the VP. It generally requires a preverbal position. Furthermore, _always_ usually refers to recurrent events, not to a continuous process.

Answer (score 1):

"Always" implies a decision process that never goes any other way, whereas "continuously" describes a situation where an uninterrupted process is the state of being.

Between the two "continuously" appears to be the more accurate choice. Adverb placement is a matter of style.